# How do I add Html Helper in mvc using ViewBag

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, html-helper, helper, viewbag

I have a textarea that I need to change input type in certain conditions. I want to send this information as a ViewBag parameter, but I can't figure out how to do it. I though this in  controller:

```
if(inputtext == 1)
  ViewBag.TextBox = @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Name, new { @class =\"inputtext\"})
if(inputtext == 2)
  ViewBag.TextBox = @Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.Name, new { @class =\"inputtext2\"})
```

my view looks like this:

```
@Html.Raw(ViewBag.TextBox)
```

But don't work. Any ideas on how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

in your controller:

```
if(A){ ViewBag.NameControlType = "textbox" }
if(B){ ViewBag.NameControlType = "textarea" }
```

in your cshtml:

```
@if(null != (ViewBag.NameControlType as string))
{
    if(ViewBag.NameControlType == "textbox")
    {
        Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Name, new { @class ="inputtext"})
    }
    if(ViewBag.NameControlType == "textarea")
    {
        Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.Name, new { @class = "inputtext2")
    }
}
```